# How to perform the ranking in mysql basis on partition

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
        periodid,percent_diff,
        @rn := IF(@PREV = periodid, @rn + 1, 1) AS rank,
        @PREV := periodid AS cutomerId
    FROM testing_ny AS a
    JOIN (SELECT @PREV := NULL, @rn := 0) AS vars
    ORDER BY periodid desc
```

Table script & insert script

```
CREATE TABLE `testing_ny` (
  `periodid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `percent_diff` decimal(20,5) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

```
insert  into `testing_ny`(`periodid`,`percent_diff`) values 
(967,0.10000),
(967,0.10000),
(967,0.20000),
(967,0.20000),
(968,0.50000),
(968,0.50000),
(968,0.10000),
(968,0.20000);
```

**output  :**

[image]

**But I need below ranking:**

**How to achieve this ranking.**

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must add one more variable to store previous `percent_diff` and use nested `IF()` (or one complex `CASE`).

Comment: ```
CREATE TABLE `testing_ny` (
  `periodid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `percent_diff` decimal(20,5) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


insert  into `testing_ny`(`periodid`,`percent_diff`) values 
(967,0.10000),
(967,0.10000),
(967,0.20000),
(967,0.20000),
(968,0.50000),
(968,0.50000),
(968,0.10000),
(968,0.20000);
```

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  @rn := CASE WHEN @periodid = periodid AND @percent_diff = percent_diff
                    THEN @rn
                    WHEN @periodid = periodid
                    THEN @rn + 1
                    ELSE 1
                    END AS rank,
        @periodid := periodid AS cutomerId,
        @percent_diff := percent_diff percent_diff
    FROM testing_ny AS a
    JOIN (SELECT @periodid := NULL, @rn := 0, @percent_diff := NULL ) AS vars
ORDER BY periodid desc, percent_diff;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bfcd92ede6bba15161d2eb3f6e388677)

PS. I cannot understand why rank is calculated in values ordered as 0.5 - 0.1 - 0.2. I have used ascending ordering.